# C++ Splitt string and remove specific part of string

Tags: c++

I want to save only dates in a vector and remove time. How can I do it in the best way?

```
string text = "16.04.2021 02:00";
char space_char = ' ';
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string token;
std::istringstream tokenStream(text);
while (std::getline(tokenStream, token, space_char))
{
    tokens.push_back(token);
    
}
for (const auto& str : tokens) {
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: your code does what you want, no? Whats the issue?

Comment: Are all the strings in *exactly that format*? Or are you wanting to parse a larger body of text? Because for what you have there I would use `tokens.push_back(text.substr(0, 10));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I got your problem right, but as Galik commented: if all your strings have this *exact* format, the easiest solution probably would be

```cpp
tokens.push_back(text.substr(0, 10));
```

If this is not the case but you can at least say that the string does not contain any additional spaces I would suggest:

```cpp
tokens.push_back(text.substr(0, text.find_last_of(' ')));
```

If your input strings are more complex you might want to use [std::regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).